# Python 3: Shared packages: Returning results and errors from imported functions

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling

I am creating a Python 3.4 module (possibly sharing upon [PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi)) and I want to clarify what is the proper and expected way of handling results and errors returned from an imported function from my package.

I am reading [Effective Python](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0134034287), but I am still confused.

There are so many possibilities, I just want to handle Python 3 results from an imported function properly.

Should the `result` and `error` handling of an imported function:

1. Return `result` but then throw `exception` upon error?
2. Return a tuple of `result, error`?

And if the preferred choice is tuple, then should:

1. Upon success, `result` can be anything (is this correct?), but then should `error` be `None` or should it be `False`?
2. Upon failure, then should `result` be `None` or should it be `False`, and `error` should then return internally caught `Exception` or what?

Thank you for your feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should throw an exception upon error. This enable lot of advance construction like proper object destruction like with the `with` keyword for instance.

If you raise an exception you don't care about `result` as your function will not return "in a normal way". So the instruction on the left on your function call will not be executed as well the rest of the `try` block.

Comment: Thank you for your response. In reference to the first line of your response, I am not following the combination of 'throw an exception upon error' and `with` keyword? I understand `with` used for example `open()`.

Comment: In your example, it will manage to automatically close the file upon exception. This construction ensure that you not forget do manage "Something that matter" on errors (that can be closing a file, releasing a Mutex, etc...).